# Exclusion script using Journey Entry data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

I have a Journey which inserts all my Orders, after 6 hours of wait time I want to send an Abandoned Cart email to the customer. To achieve this I plan to exclude any "status!=pending" rows using Exclusion Scripts within the email send activity itself.

This is the only way I can think of doing it as using decision splits just doesn't work with multiple orders (it will simply find the first order).

In my Journey I have an entry data point labelled `Order:Id` but it doesn't allow me to use it in the script. This is what my script currently looks like:

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Order_Salesforce","Id", Order:Id))>0
```

*(I was going to entually add additional criteria for the status)*

This is the error I get

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AttributeValue()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attributevalue.htm) function to output entry Data Extension value.

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Order_Salesforce","Id", AttributeValue("Order:Id")))>0
```

One thing to note is that this function does not error when parameter is not present on subscriber or entry Data Extension, instead it produces an empty value.